# Regex Find last character is an alphabet

Tags: java, regex

Hi everyone I am new here and I would like to know how to find in a string, last character is an alphabet. my string goes like this:

```
 String a = "1:50A"
 String b = "E20S"
 String c = "1:20A"
 String d = "1:23B"
 String e = "1:43C"
 final String REGEX = "([a-z]*[A-Z])+$";;
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(a);
list.add(b);
list.add(c);
list.add(d);
list.add(e);

for(String s : list){
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(s);

if(match.find()){
    //Do something with this
}

else{
     //do something with this
}
```

I want to create a Regular expression in term that it will only search for the last character and if it is a capitalized alphabet.

Comment: Do you have any fruit from your labor to share?

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: Have you attempted to write the code that does what you need? What problems are you having getting it done?

Comment: yes I do ([a-z]*[A-Z])$ is this how it works? but it search fail? @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: That's not a java program. You need to post the whole program you've written to do this.

Comment: I find your English unclear.  Are you asking how to determine whether the last character of a String is a capital letter?

Comment: @DavidWallace here is what im trying to do I edited it

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencilshere what im trying to do  edited it

Comment: @HerbWolfe here is what im trying to do edited it

Comment: Showing different non-working code doesn't tell us what you're trying to do.  Are you asking how to determine whether the last character of a String is a capital letter?

Comment: @DavidWallace yes david, im trying to determine if the last character in a string is an alphabet its stated in the Title: "Regex Find last character is an alphabet"

Comment: Yeah, I didn't understand your title.  It made no sense to me.  Is there a reason to use regular expressions, or could you just use something like `Character.isUpperCase(myString.charAt(myString.length()-1))` ?

Comment: Your regex despite having some unnecessary elements should be able to test if last character is uppercase alphabetic character. What results you expect and what you get instead?

Comment: because I am processing multiple of input in which the last alphabet could change to any other alphabet. whereas the front part of the string is the same example:

1:20 could be 
1:20A
1:20B
1:20C
and so on...

so I have to check the last character
why I checking is because:
sometime the input could be 
1:E20
so it makes no sense if I have to substring every single input.. so that why I am asking for REGEX. Unless you have a better call? thanks for advice however the solution is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Why not just loop through the string in reverse and search for a letter? Regex seems like overkill.

Comment: @pushkin cause I'm processing ranging from 1000++ data if I were to loop one by one the code would be inefficient

Comment: @nasrulsufihaq But internally a regex would still need to loop through the string. I don't think regex is more efficient than a simple loop.

Comment: @pushkin its okay.. forget it I use different method in to check instead. instead im checking for the other fields to compare. thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regular expression would match strings ending in a capital letter

```
(.*[A-Z])$
```

The problem with your expression was the `[a-z]*` which matches zero or more lower case letters, your input has colon (:) and numbers too which it would not match

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using this Regular Expression

```
(.*\p{Lu})$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/loskH5/1)

Using Regular Expression for this trivial task would do the work but that would not be an optimal solution.  `.*` is a greedy quantifier and involves a lot of backtracking.

A more optimal solution would be just to check the last character of your String.

```
String a = "1:50A";
String b = "E20S";
String c = "1:20A";
String d = "1:23B";
String e = "1:43C";

ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList < String > ();
list.add(a);
list.add(b);
list.add(c);
list.add(d);
list.add(e);

for (String s: list) {
    char ch = s.charAt(s.length()-1);
    if (ch>='A' && ch<='Z') {
        //Do something with this
        System.out.println("match");
    } else {
        //do something with this
        System.out.println("no match");
    }
}
```